# Python3: Keep compiler runnning in background

Tags: python-3.x

On my Raspberry Pi I often run python3 scripts (called by crontab).

And each time the compiler needs to be loaded ...

Is it possible to keep the compiler running 'as a daemon' in background?

Comment: What do you mean by "*keep the compiler running*"; could you rephrase this to actually explain what you want the semantics to be like?

Comment: First I call a script with python3 e.g.: `python3 script.py` .

Then the python executable is loaded (takes too long).

Then the script is loaded.

So if the compiler would already be loaded (in mem) it would be much faster :)